# Merging excel data and activeXbuttons

Tags: vba, excel

I have an issue with Excel Macro. I am trying to merge 34 different excel sheets into one single summary sheet.

All sheet contain data and **`ActiveXbuttons`** linked with Macro. Just like copy paste I want to do the exact operation using Macros.

So in the final sheet I want data and buttons which are in the previous sheets to be as the output.

I tried the following code which copies data but the buttons are not present and the tabs are not in the correct order.

```
Sub MergeAllWorkBook()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim ws2 As Worksheet
    Dim lRow As Long, lCol As Long, lRow2 As Long
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim offsetVal As Long
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Sheets("SYNTHESE").Cells.ClearFormats
    Sheets("SYNTHESE").Cells.ClearContents
    Sheets("SYNTHESE").Activate
    offsetVal = 1
    For Each ws In Worksheets
    If ws.Name <> "SYNTHESE" Then
    With ws
    lRow = .UsedRange.Rows(.UsedRange.Rows.Count).Row
    Debug.Print lRow
    lCol = .UsedRange.Columns(.UsedRange.Columns.Count).Column
    Debug.Print lCol
    Set rng = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(lRow, lCol))
    With rng.Copy
      End With
    End With
    Worksheets("SYNTHESE").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset    
    (offsetVal,0).PasteSpecial (xlPasteAll) 'offsetVal = offsetVall 
   End If 
   Next  ws
End Sub
```

Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: Could you please format your text to make it more readable?

Comment: I CAN REFRAME MY QUESTION SO its like I am trying to merge 34 excel sheets which contains data and ActiveXbuttons using Macro and the above code when I tried it worked partially but to get the actual output I needed can anyone help me out

Comment: What do you mean "tabs are in the wrong order"?

Comment: For ex; Sheet1 has a list of data and some Activebuttons. When you click on that button, it connects to Sheet3!!similarly Sheet3 's active buttons connect to Sheet 10 an so on
So the thing is I have merged all the data for now but none of the buttons are popping out into the Master Sheet.

Comment: Do you mean you want Sheet 1's buttons to process Sheet 1's data, Sheet 2's buttons to process Sheet 2, etc. Are the buttons on each sheet processing the wrong sheet's data? Is that your problem? You won't get the help you are seeking if you don't provide enough information to make your problem clear.

Comment: The buttons are not even showing up in the sheet 35 when I am trying to combine using Macro and I want all buttons to do the same function like how they were created and linked!!
Lets say in Sheet 35, I am writing a code for combining all the 34 sheets I should see all data and buttons like how it was working in their original sheets and display it as an output

Comment: Sorry but you are not making yourself clear. Yes, I understand overall what you are trying to do but restating that rather than providing the details of what your code is actually managing to achieve is not helping anyone, including you.

Comment: Again a small problem!! now people are telling me, they need only some sheets which need to be taken as output!! for ex;  I have SHEET1, SHEET2, SHEET3,SHEET4 and they need only SHEET2, SHEET3 's data to be displayed as output so can anyone help me to modify the above code

Answer (score 0):

Neither `Copy` nor `PasteSpecial` will copy an ActiveX control using the normal Excel interface, even if you copy a whole worksheet. So its not too surprising that in VBA the corresponding methods of objects such as `Range` and `Worksheet` do not copy ActiveX controls either.

Of course, ActiveX controls can be copied from one worksheet to another so suggest you play around with the macro recorder to determine how to copy and paste a control - i.e. discover which worksheet objects/methods/properties are involved. Once you have discovered these you will probably need to play around a bit further to ensure that when pasting the controls into another worksheet (such as "SYNTHESE") that the buttons are positioned correctly and are associated with the correct macro's.

The macro recorder can be your friend  and help you to understand which objects, properties and methods are relevant to what you are trying to achieve but you need to use it creatively rather than blindly following the clunky code it generates.

Comment: Tried the following code below the main code which I updated previously in this page  but still not working. Except buttons everything is fine and I know I am missing something but!!
Sub CopyImages_Controls()
Dim sh As Shape
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim selRange As Range
    For Each ws In Worksheets
        If ws.Name <> "SYNTHESE" Then
    For Each sh In ws.Shapes
        sh.copy
        Sheets("SYNTHESE").Cells(sh.TopLeftCell.Row, sh.TopLeftCell.Column).Activate
        Worksheets("SYNTHESE").PasteSpecial
     MsgBox sh.Name & "---" & sh.TopLeftCell.Row
    Next sh
    End If
    Next wsEnd Sub

Comment: Why don't you edit your question to add your new code. Your new code is virtually unreadable in its present format.

Comment: Sorry I am new to this forum !! Please find below in a readable format

Comment: And "its not working" how? Failing on a line of code? Working but not doing what you want. You might want to read this http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/

Comment: Its executing but I am just getting the fields and data. The ActiveButtons which are inserted in the other sheets are not showing up  and I don't know whether I am doing anything wrong!!

Comment: If the buttons from each worksheet being copied are always in the same place on each 'copied-from' sheet you are probably be placing them on top of each other in SYNTHESE as you haven't added anything to manage where you are copying to. If they have the same shape as well...

Comment: ya but is there any code i am missing in the above program and if there is one, suggest me what to include so that i can get the buttons diaplayed and functioning in the summary sheet SYNTHESE

Comment: Is your code failing or not? This is the last question of clarification I'll ask. If you can't answer simple diagnostic questions adequately why should anyone persevere with helping you?

Answer (score 0):

```
  Sub MergeAllWorkBook()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim ws2 As Worksheet
Dim lRow As Long, lCol As Long, lRow2 As Long
Dim rng As Range
Dim offsetVal As Long
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Sheets("SYNTHESE").Cells.ClearFormats
Sheets("SYNTHESE").Cells.ClearContents
Sheets("SYNTHESE").Activate
offsetVal = 1
For Each ws In Worksheets
If ws.Name <> "SYNTHESE" Then
With ws
lRow = .UsedRange.Rows(.UsedRange.Rows.Count).Row
Debug.Print lRow
lCol = .UsedRange.Columns(.UsedRange.Columns.Count).Column
Debug.Print lCol
Set rng = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(lRow, lCol))
With rng.Copy
  End With
End With
Worksheets("SYNTHESE").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset    
(offsetVal,0).PasteSpecial (xlPasteAll) 'offsetVal = offsetVall
```

End If 
   Next  ws

### End Sub

```
    Sub CopyImages_Controls() 
    Dim sh As Shape 
    Dim ws As Worksheet 
    Dim selRange As Range 
    For Each ws In Worksheets
    If ws.Name <> "SYNTHESE" Then 
    For Each sh In ws.Shapes 
    sh.copy 
    Sheets("SYNTHESE").Cells(sh.TopLeftCell.Row,                       
    sh.TopLeftCell.Column).Activate Worksheets("SYNTHESE").PasteSpecial 
     MsgBox sh.Name & "---" & sh.TopLeftCell.Row 
    Next sh 
    End If 
   Next ws
   End Sub
```